# Directory node repeats?

Tags: php, html, relative-path

This is my Directory structure:

- admin

  - admin_login.php
- include

  - header.php
- template

  - about_us.php
  - contact_us.php
- index.php

and some other folders...

Now in `about_us.php` and `contact_us.php` I'm including `header.php` like this:

```
require_once('../include/header.php');
```

Its getting included, no problems there.

But in `header.php`, I'm referring to the same files again(Because I'm trying to build a Navigation bar) :

```
<ul class='tab-links'>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li>               <a href="template/contact_us.php">Contact</a></li>
          <li>               <a href="template/about_us.php">About</a></li>
          <li>               <a href="admin/admin_login.php">Admin Area</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, when I click on any of them(except index.php), the URL is like this:

```
http://proj.loc/Practice/template/about_us.php
```

But after that, when I click on any other of the Navigation links, it causes the directory node to repeat:

```
http://proj.loc/Practice/template/template/about_us.php
```

and then obviously causes the "**Not Found**" error. Am I missing something here that;s really basic? Kindly enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the HTML `<base>` directive

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: This might affect other links outside of the header file.

Comment: That is certainly true, but I'm assuming you want all the relative links in your website to function the same way. Or at least, be based on the, uh, same base.

Comment: @Aeolun: Could you point out as to why my code is not working, I really need to understand this

Comment: If you use relative URL's without the base tag, the relative URL is always assumed to start from the last directory. So if you are in `/project/template/about_us.php`, with a link to `template/about_us.php` on the page, when you click on the link it'll use a base of `/project/template/` and then add `template/about_us.php` resulting in `/project/template/template/about_us.php`

Answer (score 1):

Just save your base url to a constant and use it where ever you put a link, so that you can make absolute url always

```
define("BASEURL","http://proj.loc/Practice/");

<ul class='tab-links'>
          <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo BASEURL; ?>index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo BASEURL; ?>template/contact_us.php">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo BASEURL; ?>template/about_us.php">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo BASEURL; ?>admin/admin_login.php">Admin Area</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That would still mean a little bit of hardcoding,right(hardcoding the base url)? Could you please point out the problem in my code & why is it arising?